# In the "tall cache assumption" what does $\Omega$ represent?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation, computation-models, cpu-cache

Within the field of cache-oblivious algorithms the ideal cache model is used for determining the cache complexity of an algorithm.  One of the assumptions of the ideal cache model is that it models a "tall cache".  This is given by the statement $Z = \Omega(L^2)$.  Where $Z$ is the size of the cache and $L$ is the size of the cache line.  What does $\Omega$ represent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the lower bound counterpart to O($\cdot$). Z is larger than some constant times $L^2$

Answer (score -1):

It's called "asymptotic lower bound" - https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-omega-notation

Comment: Welcome to the site! We, like all Stack Exchange sites, are looking for actual answers, not links to other sites.